# How can I vertically center content within a closed Dojo Titlepane?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I have a dojo titlepane that contains a button on the left-hand side and a paragraph of text on the right-hand side. I would like to be able to vertically center align the button in regard to the paragraph of text and would like to avoid using tables. I need a solution that will work in IE7+. For whatever it's worth, I'm using Dojo 1.3.2 (yes...I know it's old). The titlepane is initially closed until the user decides to open it.

Here's an example of the titlepane contents:

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right: 5px;">
        <input type="submit" name="access" id="access" value="Access" STYLE="font-size:8pt" />
    </div>
    <div style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla placerat vulputate tortor, sit amet malesuada quam vulputate vel. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus ut rutrum nisl. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent rhoncus nisi vitae augue tincidunt elementum. Phasellus a lorem dolor. Aliquam erat felis, ultrices eget lacinia non, rutrum a massa. Mauris et est dui, ut rutrum orci. Curabitur pulvinar porta risus, ac lobortis lorem volutpat ut. Etiam fringilla hendrerit diam at faucibus. Donec condimentum lacinia sem, quis aliquet mauris tincidunt nec. Ut sit amet urna lectus, vel volutpat ipsum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin id orci sit amet turpis sagittis adipiscing nec nec enim. Maecenas vulputate, velit a commodo ultricies, nisl nisl tristique lorem, ut lacinia mauris felis eget velit. Vestibulum sit amet dictum tellus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's also worth mentioning that I do not know the height of my container, as I know there are solutions out there where the container height is hard-coded in css.

Comment: Care to make a jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide that. If I get some additional spare time, I will do so. In my initial attempt, I had problems getting Dojo and jsfiddle to cooperate. Additionally, I'm wondering what versions of IE are supported by jsfiddle. I tried it with IE8, and it didn't seem to display properly.

Comment: @Scott - You are right about jsfiddle and IE, but it's easier to copy your code and make some test file when You use jsfiddle anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is working, but only on IE8+ (maybe my ieTester is wrong, so You should check it). You will have to modify your HTML a little:

```
<div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right: 5px; display: table; ">
    <p style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; width: 50px;">
            <input type="submit" name="access" id="access" value="Access" STYLE="font-size:8pt ;" />
        </p>

        <div style="float: right; margin-right: 5px; width: 300px;">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla placerat vulputate tortor, sit amet malesuada quam vulputate vel. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus ut rutrum nisl. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Praesent rhoncus nisi vitae augue tincidunt elementum. Phasellus a lorem dolor. Aliquam erat felis, ultrices eget lacinia non, rutrum a massa. Mauris et est dui, ut rutrum orci. Curabitur pulvinar porta risus, ac lobortis lorem volutpat ut. Etiam fringilla hendrerit diam at faucibus. Donec condimentum lacinia sem, quis aliquet mauris tincidunt nec. Ut sit amet urna lectus, vel volutpat ipsum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin id orci sit amet turpis sagittis adipiscing nec nec enim. Maecenas vulputate, velit a commodo ultricies, nisl nisl tristique lorem, ut lacinia mauris felis eget velit. Vestibulum sit amet dictum tellus.</p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- display: table; end -->
</div>
```

So first of all:

1. You have to wrap `div` with `p` inteo `div` containing `input` so it know how hight it is.
2. Add this wraper `display: table` style.
3. Put an extra element to wrap the `input`, this element must have those `CSS` `float: left; width: somepx` and `display:table-ceill`.
4. Remember to give `width: somepx` to the `div` with `p` (Your text).
5. Try to use `CSS` classes instead of inline styles.

PS
Allways remember to put jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jnCU4/

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. It appears that [IE7 does not support display: table](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp). However, when my customer phases out IE7 support, I may very well end up going this route.

Comment: @Scott - You can convince him using this link: http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp In our company we don't support IE7.